# Quarkus Panache Mongodb possible queries

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

While using Quarkus with [Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache) I get pretty frustrated as I wish to understand how its working but can't as its not debug friendly.
Some things are written too abstract [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#simplified-queries) and I wish to just write panache queries without deep knowledge of the panache, BSON parser, MongoDB driver, mongodb,... implementations.

1. Can I use a Collection on `status in ?1`?
2. How to debug queries? *Sometimes I get empty result on a like query e.g. `status in ?1` but don't know why*
3. Can someone please provide examples for the usual operators like `AND`, `OR`, `IN`, `EQUALS`, `GREATER THAN`,...?
4. How to index fields out of the code.

There are many other examples on stack overflow which I can't even follow anymore as I don't get how to write and know these usages. It just doesn't look simple anymore.
I am trying since month to get my application to work on production but failing always on the database level. Please help to get more understanding of panache.

Answer (score 2):

With MongoDB with Panache you can write queries in two styles:

1. PanacheQL, which is a subset of JPQL (the query language of JPA), a query language very close to the WHERE clause of an SQL query.
2. Native MongoDB query, for convenience JSON can be written with single quote instead of double quote.

The easiest is of course PanacheQL, while using native MongoDB query you can embrace the full power of MongoDB query language (but you'll need to write JSON query).

If you are using PanacheQL, you can check the generated query by setting DEBUG log level to the logger `io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime` as explained in the [Query debugging](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#query-debugging) of the guide.

On the guide, there is some examples of PanacheQL queries, if you feel that more should be added please open an enhanement request with some example you would want to be added (or even a PR !).

To answer your questions regarding the queries

> Can I use a Collection on status in ?1?

Yes, this is supported.

> How to debug queries?

You can enable query logging, and play the same query directly on MongoDB (using the mongo shell or any MongoDB UI).

> Can someone please provide examples for the usual operators like AND, OR, IN, EQUALS, GREATER THAN,...?

There is examples on the [Simplified queries](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#simplified-queries) section and we provide the list of operators supported, among us AND, OR (but you can't mix both), IN, = , >=, <=, ... There isn't an example for all of them but you can find plenty example of SQL WHERE clause with them.

Here are a few sample (not tested)

```
People.list("name = ?1 and country = ?2", "Doe", "France");
People.list("name = ?1 or country = ?2", "Doe", "France");
People.list("age >= ?1 or cage <= ?2", 10, 60);
People.list("country in ?1", List.of("France", "Germany"));
```

> How to index fields out of the code

If you talk about automatic MongoDB index creation, it's not supported. There is however [enhancement request](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9801) to support it, or to more generally support MongoDB database migration.

Comment: thx, can you also tell me how to limit native queries? currently I don't get how to write `Document` queries so I use `BasicDBObject` instead to generate a `json`.

Comment: `Document` is a convenience class, provided by the MongoDB Java driver to create BSON document. You can use it very easily, for exemple to create a BSON `{"field": "value"}` you can do `new Document().append("field", "value");`.

Comment: A okay that's missing in the documentation how to use `Document`s. Do you have any good link where I can see how to use these e.g. regex, sorting, etc... ?

Comment: To understand how to use MongoDB Document, the best place is the MongoDB driver reference documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/

Comment: after days investing regex, I couldn't make it work without heavy workaround. as the regex `$regex` comes with double quotes. So currently I need to convert my query into a json and then I use another regex to remove the quotes from my generated query. Thats ugly. also when I use the mongo document functions like `gte("age", 55)` then it doesn't work while manual stuff like `new Document("$gte", age)` works. I feel a bit left alone using quarkus. I fight with so many libraries which the framework should abstract and explain better.

Comment: @YunaBraska do you have a reproducer project that shows the issue with `$regex`? You talk about èmongo document functions like get("age", 55)', those are not Document but Bson filter. We didn't support Bson filter inside MongoDB with Panache, if you think it'll be a good addition please open an enhancement request